# Azure AD B2C extract array claim from id_token_hint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have setup a SignUp with email invitation flow as described [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite)

The `id_token_hint` looks like this:

```
{
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "00BFDFB35FF5994E543B5D8CE74B37FC5E702294",
    "x5t": "AL_fs1_1mU5UO12M50s3_F5wIpQ",
    "typ": "JWT"
  }.{
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "email@domain.com",
    "roles": [
      "role1",
      "role2",
      "role3"
    ],
    "nbf": 1651067986,
    "exp": 1651068286,
    "iss": "xx",
    "aud": "xx"
  }.[Signature]
```

and I try to extract the roles to a `stringCollection` Claim, so that I can use it later. The claim is defined like this:

```
      <ClaimType Id="InvitationRoles">
        <DisplayName>Invitation Roles</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Invitation Roles</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
```

I added the following to the `IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims` ClaimsProvider TechnicalProfile:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="InvitationRoles" PartnerClaimType="roles"/>
```

and this to the `RelyingParty` TechnicalProfile PolicyProfile:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="InvitationRoles" PartnerClaimType="roles" />
```

But I only get the first value of the array shown in the Application Insights Debug Logging:

```
Claims
InvitationRoles: [role1]
ReadOnlyEmail: email@domain.com
email: email@domain.com
```

Do I miss something or is this not supported?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I what I did as a workaround is instead of an array send comma separated string (MAX size is 256 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if given references can narrow down the issue.

Please check if this > [Default value for stringCollection in Azure AD B2C custom policy - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/780317/default-value-for-stringcollection-in-azure-ad-b2c.html) can give idea to work around

> 1. Define the claims schema.
> 2. Add the claims transformation rule.
> 3. To the required Technical Profile, **add the string claim as the
>    output claim and the claims transformation rule to transform it to a
>    stringCollection claim**.
> 4. Finally add the claim as output claim

- You can extract claims from id_token_hint using the instructions and
  sample mentioned here - [AAD-b2c-id-token-hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint)

> Note: But in some cases The token's retrieved from B2C do not contain all
> the information about the user and its claim or attributes. You may
> need to use the Graph API to query the user for its information .

You may check this [c# - Azure B2C How to retrieve Built-In User Claims/Attributes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57675567/azure-b2c-how-to-retrieve-built-in-user-claims-attributes) On how to get array of them programmatically.

The output you have looks like extractedItem from [getsingleitemfromstringcollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#getsingleitemfromstringcollection) claim stransformation where string ClaimTypes that are produced after this ClaimsTransformation gets the first item in the collection.

Please check if you can make use of AddItemToStringCollection to add to other roles and then output the extracted item:
[***example-of-additemtostringcollection***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#example-of-additemtostringcollection)

**References:**

1. [azure ad b2c - How to extract multiple values from id_token_hint
   into specific claims? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620877/how-to-extract-multiple-values-from-id-token-hint-into-specific-claims)
2. [azure ad b2c -  id_token_hint parameter does not contain an accepted issuer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639011/azureb2c-custom-policy-invalid-request-the-provided-id-token-hint-parameter-doe)